# Help me on this is, seems not be within my article's page border

Tags: longtable, beamerarticle, page

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{TYPES OF BANKS}
     \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c|c|c}

    \textbf{BANK} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{NOTE}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{FUNCTION}} \\ \hline \hline
    & & \\
    \textbf{Central Bank} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{i. Country Monetary Policy} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ii. Supervise and regulate financial firms} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{iii. Provide financial services} \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Retail/Commercial Banks} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{i. Checking and Savings Account} \\
    i. Public Sector Banks & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Majority stake; Government.  } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ii. Certificates of deposits.} \\
    ii. Private Sector Banks & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Majority stake; Private Individuals.  } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{iii. Safe deposit boxes} \\
    iii. Foreign Banks & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Headquarters in Foreign Countries.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{iv. Loans during Mortgages} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v. Credit cards etc.} \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Development/Industrial Banks} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{i. Provision of Industrial capital in terms share and debenture issues.} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ii. Longterm credit/fund facilities for industrial activity expansion and diversification.} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{iii. Aid in purchase of land, plant and machinery.} \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Foreign Exchange Banks} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{i. Financing of Foreign Trade} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ii. Acts as referee, collecting and supplying information about foreign customers.} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{iii.  Providing remittance facilities} \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Co-operative Banks} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Jointly serving of Common Interest} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{i. Grant loans for productive purposes.} \\
    i. Primary Credit Socities &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ii. Charges moderate interest rate. } \\
    ii. Central Co-operative Banks &       &  \\
    iii. State Co-operative Banks &       &  \\
    \end{tabular*}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Why all these strange `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}`?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: we cant help you if you will not extend your code snipped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. and please consider @samcarter comments above ...

Comment: BTW, you do not need to do all the numbering manually, latex has `enumerate` for this.

Comment: @samcarter It’s a nice feature of Excel2LaTeX

Comment: @egreg Oh, great. Without excel I am safe from such a mess :)

Comment: @PrinceMcClone If you can clean up your table to remove all unnecessary commands, it would give people willing to help you a better start to tackle your problem.

Comment: @samcarter you right.. just cleaned up the unnecessary commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

above table is produced by help of packages `booktabs`, `makecell`, `tabularx` and  `enumitem. its form is very dependent form text width, if it is narrowed, table will lost most of its beauty :-(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                        topsep     = 0pt       ,
                        partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                        leftmargin = *         ,
                        label      = \roman*.,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\caption{TYPES OF BANKS}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
  \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
                                          >{\RaggedRight}p{0.32\linewidth}
                                 @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{BANK}            & \thead{NOTE}  & \thead{FUNCTION}                          \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Central Bank}   &               &   \begin{enumerate}
                                        \item  Country Monetary Policy
                                        \item Supervise and regulate financial firms
                                        \item Provide financial services
                                            \end{enumerate}                         \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Retail/Commercial Banks}
                        &               & Checking and Savings Account              \\
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Public Sector Banks
\item Private Sector Banks
\item Foreign Banks
    \end{enumerate}     &   Majority stake; Government\par
                            Majority stake; Private Individuals\par
                            Headquarters in Foreign Countries
                                        &   \begin{enumerate}
                                        \item Certificates of deposits.
                                        \item Safe deposit boxes
                                        \item Loans during Mortgage,
                                        \item Credit cards etc.
                                            \end{enumerate}                         \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Development/Industrial Banks}
                    &                   &   \begin{enumerate}
                                        \item Provision of Industrial capital in
                                          terms share and debenture issues.
                                        \item Longterm credit/fund facilities for industrial activity expansion and diversification.
                                        \item Aid in purchase of land, plant and machinery.
                                            \end{enumerate}                         \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Foreign Exchange Banks}
                    &                   &   \begin{enumerate}
                                        \item Financing of Foreign Trade
                                        \item Acts as referee, collecting and supplying information about foreign customers.
                                        \item Providing remittance facilities
                                            \end{enumerate}                         \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Co-operative Banks}\bigskip
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Primary Credit Societies
\item Central Co-operative Banks
\item State Co-operative Banks
    \end{enumerate}
                & Jointly serving of Common Interest
                                        &   \begin{enumerate}
                                        \item Grant loans for productive purposes.
                                        \item Charges moderate interest rate.
                                            \end{enumerate}                         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is perfect

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution for your table, that is not likely to be suitably compressed in the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newlength{\titemwd}
\newcommand{\titem}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#1 }%
  \hangindent\titemwd\hangafter0
  #2\\
}
\newcommand{\nitem}[1]{%
  {\footnotesize \titem{}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{TYPES OF BANKS}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\medskip

\settowidth{\titemwd}{iii. }

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
  >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Functions} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bank} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Central Bank}} \tabularnewline
\titem{i.}{Country Monetary Policy}
\titem{ii.}{Supervise and regulate financial firms}
\titem{iii.}{Provide financial services}
&
\tabularnewline
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Retail/Commercial Banks}} \tabularnewline
\titem{i.}{Checking and Savings Account}
\titem{ii.}{Certificates of deposits}
\titem{iii.}{Safe deposit boxes}
\titem{iv.}{Loans during Mortgages}
\titem{v.}{Credit cards etc.}
&
\titem{i.}{Public Sector Banks}
\nitem{Majority stake; Government.}
\titem{ii.}{Private Sector Banks}
\nitem{Majority stake; Private Individuals.}
\titem{iii.}{Foreign Banks}
\nitem{Headquarters in Foreign Countries.}
\tabularnewline
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Development/Industrial Banks}} \tabularnewline
\titem{i.}{Provision of Industrial capital in terms 
           share and debenture issues.}
\titem{ii.}{Longterm credit/fund facilities for industrial 
            activity expansion and diversification.}
\titem{iii.}{Aid in purchase of land, plant and machinery.}
&
\tabularnewline
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Foreign Exchange Banks}} \tabularnewline
\titem{i.}{Financing of Foreign Trade}
\titem{ii.}{Acts as referee, collecting and supplying 
           information about foreign customers.}
\titem{iii.}{Providing remittance facilities}
&
\tabularnewline
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Co-operative Banks}
 (Jointly serving of Common Interest)} \tabularnewline
\titem{i.}{Grant loans for productive purposes.}
\titem{ii.}{Charges moderate interest rate.}
&
\titem{i.}{Primary Credit Societies}
\titem{ii.}{Central Co-operative Banks}
\titem{iii.}{State Co-operative Banks}
\tabularnewline
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaned-up version that may be useful.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{TYPES OF BANKS}
  \bigskip
     \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{1.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{1.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.4in}@{}}

    \textbf{BANK} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{NOTE}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{FUNCTION}} \\ \hline \hline
    & & \\
    \textbf{Central Bank} &       & Country Monetary Policy \\
          &       & Supervise and regulate financial firms \\
          &       & Provide financial services \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Retail/Commercial Banks} &       & Checking and Savings Account \\
    Public Sector Banks & Majority stake; Government  & Certificates of deposits. \\
    Private Sector Banks & Majority stake; Private Individuals.   & Safe deposit boxes \\
    Foreign Banks & Headquarters in Foreign Countries & Loans during Mortgages \\
          &       & Credit cards etc. \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Development/Industrial Banks} &       & Provision of Industrial capital in terms share and debenture issues. \\
          &       & Longterm credit/fund facilities for industrial activity expansion and diversification. \\
          &       & Aid in purchase of land, plant and machinery. \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Foreign Exchange Banks} &       & Financing of Foreign Trade \\
          &       & Acts as referee, collecting and supplying information about foreign customers. \\
          &       &  Providing remittance facilities \\
          &       &  \\
    \textbf{Co-operative Banks} & Jointly serving of Common Interest & Grant loans for productive purposes. \\
    Primary Credit Socities &       & Charges moderate interest rate.  \\
    Central Co-operative Banks &       &  \\
    State Co-operative Banks &       &  \\
    \end{tabular*}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```